# How can i use react-drag-listview with functional components to make draggable columns with antd-table?

Tags: reactjs, antd, draggable, react-functional-component

I'm trying to create a draggable table with antd, but i always use functionalcomponents in react and all the examples and doc that i found in internet is using class components and that=this stufs like. I don't know how can i use react-drag-listview library with the functional components.

```
this.state = {
  columns: [
    {
      title: <span className="dragHandler">Key</span>,
      dataIndex: "key",
      render: (text) => <span>{text}</span>,
      width: 50
    },
    {
      title: <span className="dragHandler">Name</span>,
      dataIndex: "name",
      width: 200
    },
    {
      title: <span className="dragHandler">Gender</span>,
      dataIndex: "gender",
      width: 100
    },
    {
      title: <span className="dragHandler">Age</span>,
      dataIndex: "age",
      width: 100
    },
    {
      title: <span className="dragHandler">Address</span>,
      dataIndex: "address"
    }
  ]
};

const that = this;
this.dragProps = {
  onDragEnd(fromIndex, toIndex) {
    const columns = [...that.state.columns];
    const item = columns.splice(fromIndex, 1)[0];
    columns.splice(toIndex, 0, item);
    that.setState({
      columns
    });
  },
  nodeSelector: "th",
  handleSelector: ".dragHandler",
  ignoreSelector: "react-resizable-handle"
};
```

}

This a small piece of code that I'm trying to copy from, but i don't understand it.
Even an exaple of any small code where i can see how to use with functional components it may work for me.

Tis is the url of the example above: https://codesandbox.io/s/table-column-sortable-resizable-st9bt?file=/index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Drag List View Using Functional Component

```
import "./index.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Resizable } from "react-resizable";
import { Table } from "antd";
import ReactDragListView from "react-drag-listview";

const ResizableTitle = (props) => {
  const { onResize, width, ...restProps } = props;

  if (!width) {
    return <th {...restProps} />;
  }

  return (
    <Resizable
      width={width}
      height={0}
      handle={
        <span
          className='react-resizable-handle'
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.stopPropagation();
          }}
        />
      }
      onResize={onResize}
      draggableOpts={{ enableUserSelectHack: false }}
    >
      <th {...restProps} />
    </Resizable>
  );
};

const data = [
  { key: "1", name: "Boran", gender: "male", age: "12", address: "New York" },
  { key: "2", name: "JayChou", gender: "male", age: "38", address: "TaiWan" },
  { key: "3", name: "Lee", gender: "female", age: "22", address: "BeiJing" },
  { key: "4", name: "ChouTan", gender: "male", age: "31", address: "HangZhou" },
  { key: "5", name: "AiTing", gender: "female", age: "22", address: "Xi’An" },
];

const components = { header: { cell: ResizableTitle } };

const App = () => {
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState([
    {
      title: <span className='dragHandler'>Key</span>,
      dataIndex: "key",
      render: (text) => <span>{text}</span>,
      width: 50,
    },
    {
      title: <span className='dragHandler'>Name</span>,
      dataIndex: "name",
      width: 200,
    },
    {
      title: <span className='dragHandler'>Gender</span>,
      dataIndex: "gender",
      width: 100,
    },
    {
      title: <span className='dragHandler'>Age</span>,
      dataIndex: "age",
      width: 100,
    },
    {
      title: <span className='dragHandler'>Address</span>,
      dataIndex: "address",
    },
  ]);

  const onDragEnd = (fromIndex, toIndex) => {
    setColumns((prev) => {
      const nextColumns = [...prev];
      const item = nextColumns.splice(fromIndex, 1)[0];
      nextColumns.splice(toIndex, 0, item);
      return nextColumns;
    });
  };

  const handleResize = (size, index) => {
    setColumns((prev) => {
      const nextColumns = [...prev];
      nextColumns[index] = {
        ...nextColumns[index],
        width: size.width,
      };
      return nextColumns;
    });
  };

  const tableColumns = columns.map((col, index) => ({
    ...col,
    onHeaderCell: (column) => ({
      width: column.width,
      onResize: (e, { size }) => handleResize(size, index),
    }),
  }));

  return (
    <ReactDragListView.DragColumn
      onDragEnd={onDragEnd}
      nodeSelector='th'
      handleSelector='.dragHandler'
      ignoreSelector='react-resizable-handle'
    >
      <Table bordered columns={tableColumns} dataSource={data} components={components} />
    </ReactDragListView.DragColumn>
  );
};

export default App;
```